# Quad-Word Puzzle

Tags: word, word-square

In this puzzle, you have to fill in the blanks with 4-letter words.

1. The tree branches were sticking out through Max's fence, so he had to _ _ _ _ them down.
2. Bob asked Joe to _ _ _ _ his video.
3. Amy had an _ _ _ _ on her nose.
4. Maddie wrote "_ _ _ _" on a sheet of paper, but nobody knew what she meant because it was a misspelled word.

When put into a 4x4 grid, all the words have to match in the rows and columns. As you can see in the example below, the words "swag," "will," "also," and "glow" can be read from top to bottom and from left to right.

[image]

The squares on the grid from the top-left going diagonally to the bottom-right make the mystery word. (it has to be a real word)

[image]

That's the solution to the puzzle. Figure out the mystery word.

Comment: Seems a bit off to have one of the "four-letter words" be not a word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alternative Answer

> CAUF

The tree branches were sticking out through Max's fence, so he had to _ _ _ _ them down.

> CHOP

Bob asked Joe to _ _ _ _ his video.

> HAVE

Amy had an _ _ _ _ on her nose.

> OVUM

Maddie wrote "_ _ _ _" on a sheet of paper, but nobody knew what she meant because it was a misspelled word.

> PEMF

Yielding the grid

> **C**HOP 
>  H**A**VE 
>  OV**U**M 
>  PEM**F**

Comment: Um, how can someone have an ovum on their nose?

Answer (score 0):

The mystery word is:

> taco

Answers:

> 1. The tree branches were sticking out through Max's fence, so he had to **trim** them down.
>
>  2. Bob asked Joe to **rate** his video.
>
>  3. Amy had an **itch** on her nose.
>
>  4. Maddie wrote **"meho"** on a sheet of paper, but nobody knew what she meant because it was a misspelled word.

Grid:

> T R I M
>
>  R A T E
>
>  I T C H
>
>  M E H O

Comment: Aww... I was just exploring the "itch" possibility! I like this puzzle.

Comment: A misspelled word? Really? Why couldn't it have been TACT?

Comment: I would like this puzzle more if the last word was a real word. Good answer, though!

Comment: Wait, you answered your own puzzle?

Comment: I agree with the other commentators. If you're going to use a misspelled word, it should probably be a misspelling of an actual word, involving, for example, a transposition, like some crossword variations use, and the context should point toward the correct word.